# Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{f(i)*f(i+1)}=\frac{n-1}{f(1)*f(n)}$ if $f(i)$,$f(i+1)$,$f(i+2)$..... forms an arithmetic progression?

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions, binary-operations

Well, '*' stands for a binary operation. I am asking this question because I derived the following 2 results:

If $a_{i}$'s form an arithmetic progression then,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{i+1}}+\sqrt{a_{i}}}=\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{a_{1}}+\sqrt{a_{n}}}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{a_{i+1}a_{i}}=\frac{n-1}{a_{1}a_{n}}$$

I want to ask if the same result(the generalised result) is valid for every binary operation on $f(i)$ and $f(i+1)$ if these form an arithmetic progression?

Comment: I don't fully inderstand the question. What do you mean by f(x) forms an Arithmetic progression? Because in your example is $a_i$ the A.P. or is it $\sqrt{a_i}$? But anyways if your binary operation took all pairs of inputs to 1, then the Lhs would give n and the rhs n+1.

Comment: @G Aker see the edited version.

Comment: Regarding *every* binary operation: no, it is clearly not valid for $+$ in place of $*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is that there are two different formulas

- the formula you give in the title and the second formula of your text are one thing (proof A below).
- The second formula is another (proof B).

The only connection between them being that they are intrinsically due to **telescopic cancellation** (and the fact that they deal with arithmetic progressions). I don't see any visible composition operation $\star$ generalizing these formulas.

**A) Proof of**

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{f(i)f(i+1)}=\frac{n-1}{f(1)f(n)}\tag{1}$$

We start from the LHS of (1), that we transform progressively in order to obtain finally the RHS.

An arithmetic progression can be written under the form $f(i)=ai+b$ for certain (fixed) real numbers $A$ and $B$ ($A$=ratio and $B$=$0$th term) :

With these notations, the LHS of (1) can be written as :

$$LHS=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{1}{A}\left(\frac{1}{Ai+B}-\frac{1}{A(i+1)+B}\right)$$

By telescopic cancellation :

$$LHS=\dfrac{1}{A}\left(\frac{1}{A+B}-\frac{1}{An+B}\right)$$

Finally :

$$LHS=\dfrac{1}{A}\dfrac{A(n-1)}{(A+B)(An+B)}=\dfrac{(n-1)}{f(1)f(n)}$$

which is the desired RHS.

**B)Proof of**

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{i+1}}+\sqrt{a_{i}}}=\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{a_{1}}+\sqrt{a_{n}}}\tag{2}.$$

Here as well, let us start from the LHS. Multiplying numerator and denominator of each fraction by the conjugate quantity of the denominator $\sqrt{a_{i+1}}-\sqrt{a_{i}}$ gives

$$LHS = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\sqrt{a_{i+1}}-\sqrt{a_{i}}}{a_{i+1}-a_{i}}$$

With expression $a_i=Ai+B$,

$$LHS = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\sqrt{a_{i+1}}-\sqrt{a_{i}}}{a}=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (\sqrt{a_{i+1}}-\sqrt{a_{i}})$$

finally giving, by telescopic cancellation :

$$LHS =\frac{1}{a}(\sqrt{a_{n}}-\sqrt{a_{1}})$$

It remains to multiply this result by $$\dfrac{\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{a_{1}}}{\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{a_{1}}}$$

to obtain the RHS of (2).

Comment: why $n-1$ instead of $n$ ?

Comment: ... Because in the LHS of your expression, if $i$ was ending at $i=n$, factor $f(i+1)$ in the denominator would be equal to $f(n+1)$ whereas in the RHS, one finds $f(n)$, not $f(n+1)$.

Comment: I have re-written my answer.